# Add a directory name to a URL address using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox where users can paste a URL address. I want to add a directory name to the URL before saving it in the database.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="urlTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind

```
TextBox url = urlTextbox as TextBox;
string urlString = urlTextbox.Text;
```

Let's say the urlString = "mydomain.com/123456". I want to replace it with "mydomain.com/directory/123456". mydomain.com/directory is the same for all the URLs. The last part "123456" changes only.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest seeing if your needs are met with the [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class.

```
UriBuilder url = new UriBuilder(urlTextbox.Text);
```

Now you can use the various properties to change your url.

```
string formattedUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}/directory/{2}", url.Scheme, url.Host, url.Path);
```

A better idea is to adjust the URL with another / same `UriBuilder` as noted by Jared.

```
UriBuilder url = new UriBuilder(urlTextbox.Text);
url.Path = string.Format("directory/{0}", url.Path);
```

Use this object as a `Uri` by simply doing this

```
Uri formattedUrl = url.Uri;
```

Or convert to a string if needed.

```
string formattedUrl = url.ToString();
```

You can also use `Uri.TryParse(...)` to verify if it's a valid URL being entered into the text box.

To get the individual query parameters, you can look at the `Uri` object.

```
UriBuilder url = new UriBuilder("mydomain.com/123456?qs=aaa&bg=bbb&pg=ccc");
url.Path = string.Format("directory/{0}", url.Path);

Uri formattedUrl = url.Uri;
string queryString = formattedUrl.Query;
// parse the query into a dictionary
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);

// get your parameters
string qs = parameters.Get("qs");
string bg = parameters.Get("bg");
string pg = parameters.Get("pg");
```

Comment: Or better yet, make `formattedUrl` a 2nd UriBuilder instead of a string

Comment: Great. One more thing...how can I retrieve the value of a querystring from a URL using UriBuilder. Let's say I want to retrieve the value of qs in mydomain.com/123456?qs=aaa

Comment: I've added an example of getting the parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions `Split` and `Join` to achieve your result. An example code is shown below

```
List<string> parts = urlString.Split(new char[] { '/'}).ToList();
parts.Insert(parts.Count - 1, "directory");

urlString = string.Join("/", parts);
```

Comment: Shoul be nice to show how set the URL back to the response, probly she must redirect to this new one.

Comment: @Fals I did not understand. Could you please explain?

Comment: Nevermind, I missunderstood the question, she only need to insert the directory inside the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing. Split the urlString using .split() function.

```
string[] parts = urlString.Split('/');
```

parts[parts.Length-1] will have that number. Append it to the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
//Assuming the address in urlString has the format mydomain.com/123456
string[] urlParts = urlString.Split('/');
string directory = "directory";
string finalUrl = urlParts[0] + "/" + directory + "/" + urlParts[1];
```

Be careful if the address has other "/" characters, like if preceded by *http://* or something like that.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use concatenation:
save in a temporary string

```
 temp="mydomain.com/directory/"
```

and save the changing part in another string like

```
 temp2="123456"
```

now concatenate both temp1 and temp2 like below.

```
urlString=temp1+temp2;
```